# android open the browser with ACTION_VIEW then get callback data and return to app?

Tags: android

I have an e-payment address that I call with the following command from an android app

```
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse(MyPaymentAddress));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

If the payment is made correctly, the browser will be taken to a new page that displays this information in one line:

**OK1,Tracking Code:443,Your payment is complete:XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX**

And if I click the Cancel button on the payment page, the browser will show a new page with the following information:

**CANCELL,0**

Now I do not know how to not show these pages and read this information in Activity after successful payment or cancellation and return to first activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In your Manifest :


<activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="anyname" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Then in Server side callback URL should be  "anyname://HomeActivity"
For example:

```
 <a href="anyname://HomeActivity" > go to my application </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I Solved My Problem With google DeepLink Technology